# Counting the frequency of multiple columns of a data frame

Tags: r

If I have a data frame with multiple columns (which I don't know the exact number of columns) but I know the have common in name the stock_ and the other is a number like this

```
stock_1        stock_2  stock_3       stock_4
Google         NA       Yahoo         Google
Bing  Search   Yahoo    Bing Search   NA
Google         Yahoo    Yahoo         Bing Search
```

How is it possible to count the frequency of all words of all columns and take a result like this:

```
name          frequency
Google           3
Bing Search      3
Yahoo            4
```

Comment: `unlist` + `table` should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `unlist` the dataset and use `table`

```
as.data.frame(table(unlist(df1)))
#         Var1 Freq
#1 Bing Search    3
#2      Google    3
#3       Yahoo    4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(stock_1 = c("Google", "Bing Search", "Google"), 
stock_2 = c(NA, "Yahoo", "Yahoo"), stock_3 = c("Yahoo", 
"Bing Search", 
"Yahoo"), stock_4 = c("Google", NA, "Bing Search")), 
.Names = c("stock_1", 
"stock_2", "stock_3", "stock_4"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution gives for var1 numbers 1,2 etc. and not the name of the word. Any idea from where I could see why I have this?

Comment: @Keri I think the columns are `factor `class.  Convert to `character` and it will work.  `df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.character)` and then apply the code.